# Responsive html and css using media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my previous question I asked a similar question but was using the bootstrap framework. I want to be able to create a responsive page without using bootstrap because I don't really like the grid system.

I have two divs that are centered horizontally and vertically. I would like for it to be responsive and stack up on top of each other when the window is minimized. My [code](https://codepen.io/pen/xXJNbR) on CodePen. I've attempted it a few times and I still not sure how to approach it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #about #aboutInfo{
    border: solid;

    float:none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #about #aboutInfo{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved your problem in the previous post but ok. First of all, I advise you to stop using floats because floats are history and float: none; does nothing because by default elements don't float like you have it written in your codepen. Second, I recommend you to take a closer look at Flexbox and the possibilities it brings because it really shines when it comes to responsive web design/development.

So again, solve the problem by adding the below code to your media queries:

```
#about {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And also like I told you before it's always good to use some basic CSS browser reset:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you should add

```
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

or

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

in #about.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not stacking is because you're separating your content with div tags. Make the section a col and style them like here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

In bootstrap, there is a row tag that acts like a div tag. But each of the columns are litterally "col-**" with styling behind them.

Comment: Thanks! So there's no way to achieve a responsive html using divs?

Comment: Apparently what @ivan.posokhin wrote. Thanks, Ivan! I was unaware of that :)